# How to make slideshow pause on mouseover on ColorBox

Tags: jquery, slideshow, colorbox, onmouseover

I'm trying to use ColorBox for slideshow. But I can't seem to figure out how to pause the slideshow while hovered by mouse. Searched everywhere but found nothing. I thought this should be a common request.

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Any help would be appreciated,

M@

Comment: That is mostly likely a mod to the plugin.
Note that the slideshow examples on the plug-ins page include a UI control to manually stop and start the slideshow, so the essence of the requirement is already there.

Answer (score 0):

As kevin commented:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('#cboxContent').hover(function(){
        $('.cboxSlideshow_on #cboxSlideshow').click();
    },function(){
        $('.cboxSlideshow_off #cboxSlideshow').click();
    })
});
```

Basically when the mouse is over the content we trigger the click on the stop slideshow button